# Luaのrequireがローカルディレクトリを探してくれない

Tags: lua

下記のrequireが記述されているeval.luaがあり、

```
local utils = require 'misc.utils'
```

その子ディレクトリのmiscにutils.luaがあるのですが、requireした時にそのディレクトリを見てくれないのでエラーが出てしまいます。なぜこのようなエラーがでてしまうのでしょうか。またどのように対策すれば良いのでしょうか。
スタックトレースによると下記のファイルを検索しているようです。

```
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/misc/utils.lua'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/misc/utils/init.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/misc/utils.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/misc/utils/init.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-alpha/misc/utils.lua'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/misc/utils.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/misc/utils.so'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/misc.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/misc.so'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

LUA_PATHという環境変数に`./?.lua`を追加したところちゃんとローカルディレクトリを見てくれるようになりました。